# using a loop to update data from another table into another table using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a macro that filters according to entered date and takes data from `table1` on `sheet1` to `table2` on `sheet2` manually by changing the Range line manually, `Range("J12:J18").Select`.

The data in table2 on sheet2 is arranged in months.Therefore this columns refers to september `Range("J12:J18").Select`. Could there be a way such that, data on table2 is filled in automatically upto current date month and year or maybe a creat an input box where we enter the month column on table2 where we would like the data to be inserted ?

I would glady appreciate any help by the way am still at beginner level..

```
Public mois As String, annee As String

Sub macro001()

    Dim this As Date
    Dim that As Date
    mois = 0
    année = 0

    mois = Month(Now)
    année = Year(Now)

    For x = 1 To mois
        this = Format(Date, "mm")
        that = Format(Date, "yyyy")

        this = InputBox("Insert date in format mm/yyyy", _
                        "User date", _
                        Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy"))

        that = InputBox("Insert date in format mm/yyyy", _
                        "User date", _
                        Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy"))

        mois = Format(CDate(this), "mm")
        annee = Format(CDate(that), "yyyy")

        Range("Tableau1[[#Headers],[Date réalisée RBT" & Chr(10) & "]]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Operator:= _
                                                             xlFilterValues, _
                                                             Criteria2:=Array(1, mois & "/" & annee)
        Range("Tableau1[[#Headers],[Statut sortie RBT]]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
                                                             "Rouge"
        Range("Tableau1[[#Headers],[MAJ Statut]]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= "="


        Range("M1:S1").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Défauts RBT").Select

        Range("J12:J18").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                               :=False, Transpose:=True
        Sheets("RBT-RAT ").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10

    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a formula to transpose from a row to a column. Consider the example below.

In column X, the difference between two ROW functions gives an incremental value (1, 2, 3, 4).
In column Y, an OFFSET function uses the incremental value to select cells in different columns.
Combined, the formula is `= OFFSET($A$3, 0, ROW([@X]) - ROW(Table2[[#Headers],[X]]) - 1)`.

[image: Transpose from row to column with a formula]